# Is this correct? "Being under control"

Tags: grammar

As a native speaker, how would you change following speech?

> Being under control of my parents I won't go to the party tonight.

Comment: _Thanks to my caring parents, I won't be getting into any trouble tonight_ ;^)

Comment: Another variant (by a non-native speaker), *Mom and Dad watch me like a hawk. I can't go to the party tonight.* :-)

Comment: @J.R. You cannot *possibly* be that old!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I'm a non-native but this is interesting so I'm answering.

*Being under control* is a bit rude and emphasizes the possession that you are *forcefully* under control. We often hear this from cops and soldiers... *The situation is **under control**...don't we?

> Being under control of my parents I won't go to the party tonight - means that you actually want to go to the party but then you are forcefully (house arrest..lol) not allowed to do so.

If you don't mean the above one, I'm not sure what exactly you mean by telling that.

If you want to say that my parents won't allow me to go to the party, the polite way is...

> As my parents would (certainly) deny, I won't (be able to) go to the party tonight.

The context will make this question clear and also help us answer precisely though.

Answer (score 3):

> Being under control of my parents

when it restricts your activities, we refer to as *being grounded*. So it would be better to say like it this:

> Since I *have been grounded* by my parents, I *can't* go to the party tonight.

*have been grounded* because it's an ongoing action.

*can't* is better than *won't* because the child is not able to go. *won't* makes it sound like the child does not want to go.

Answer (score 1):

as a native speaker, I would say it like this:

> My parents won't let me go to the party tonight.